# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python, valueerror

I got this error from my code:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''.
```

What does it mean? Why does it occur, and how can I fix it?

Comment: For anyone currently looking here. The error may be that one of the lines isn't in integer form. Eg: "yes" isn't in the correct form but "3" is. For this question the first line may not have any "1"s, "2"s, "3"s... to convert to an int.

Comment: i got this error when input string had space between digits. this error basically means your input string is not valid for string to integer conversion. for conversion, your string should only and only contain  following characters:  +-.0123456789

Answer (score 865):

The error message means that the string provided to `int` could not be parsed as an integer. The part at the end, after the `:`, shows the string that was provided.

In the case described in the question, the input was an *empty string*, written as `''`.

Here is another example - a string that represents a floating-point value cannot be converted directly with `int`:

```
>>> int('55063.000000')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '55063.000000'
```

Instead, convert to `float` first:

```
>>> int(float('55063.000000'))
55063
```

Comment: I'll just add, to provide more clarity for future readers, that indeed, int(float('1.0')) works when int('1.0') throws the ValueError.

Comment: This should be the accepted top answer to this question. I almost closed the page and didn't see it. Thanks!

Comment: add to answer int(float('55063.000000')) as question is get int(). Than it will  realy top answer

Comment: Why does this happen? @katyhuff

Comment: Why not update your answer as per @Kevin's comment above? This is a highly active question and should not be confusing to someone who directly search for the specific error in question title.

Comment: I think it is quite easy to handle the empty string case, just check if len(str) !=0

Comment: when I'm converting a string to float according to the above answer, it says `ValueError: could not convert string to float:`

Comment: `int(float(some_float_str))` is what I've been doing already, but I looked this up to see if there was a more idiomatic way, haven't seen any better alternative here... but it works!

Comment: This should not happen, but it does. Feel free to educate me on the usefulness of this.

Comment: What if i would need to work with a single decimal number? For example '593450.50000'

Answer (score 176):

The following work fine in Python:

```py
>>> int('5') # passing the string representation of an integer to `int`
5
>>> float('5.0') # passing the string representation of a float to `float`
5.0
>>> float('5') # passing the string representation of an integer to `float`
5.0
>>> int(5.0) # passing a float to `int`
5
>>> float(5) # passing an integer to `float`
5.0
```

However, passing the string representation of a *float*, or any other string that does not represent an integer (including, for example, an empty string like `''`) will cause a `ValueError`:

```py
>>> int('')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
>>> int('5.0')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '5.0'
```

To convert the string representation of a floating-point number to integer, it will work to convert to a float first, then to an integer (as explained in @katyhuff's comment on the question):

```py
>>> int(float('5.0'))
5
```

Comment: Wow that's incredibly silly. Why not make int() accept a string? That's exactly what I was expecting it to do and not typecast it into float first.....

Comment: typecasting into float doesn't work in my case at least.. error shown is couldnot convert int to float

Comment: @BUFU it **does** accept a string. As long as that string represents an integer.

Comment: @Alex the technique here is to convert a **string that represents a float**, to a float first, and then to an int. If your error says that it could not convert an int to a float, this implies that you **already have** an int. If your goal is to have an int, then the correct code is none at all.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I **obviously** meant a string representing a float...

Comment: Ah. In that case, the best I can offer is: Python's philosophy is that there are no "casts", only conversions (i.e., creation of a new value). Since "explicit is better than implicit" and "errors should never pass silently unless explicitly silenced", the conversion string->float->int is forced to occur in two steps - in order to make sure that the programmer acknowledges "yes, I want to discard the fractional part, if any".

Comment: Converting to `int` entails that a floating-point value wouldn't make sense; therefore, if the user tried to provide a floating-point value, there's a good chance that *the user misunderstands the purpose of the data, and has input something nonsensical*.

Comment: If you pass a variable into `int()`, you always explicitly discard the fractional part of any value (after all, there is the option to use `float()`. It accepts strings, it accepts floats, but it does not accept a string of a float... It doesn't make sense to me. But I guess as long as it's consistent in this behaviour, it's fine. Just one more grammar rule for this language.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel "Converting to int entails that a floating-point value wouldn't make sense" - well, now you're being silly. If that was true, it wouldn't accept a float - which it does. Providing a float into `int()`, there is a good chance the user wants to discard the decimals and have a whole number. (A very good reason to use `int()` and not `float()`.)

Comment: Converting to int **from a string** entails that a string **representing a floating-point value** wouldn't make sense. This is because the **reason** that we do these conversions from string, primarily, is to process user input, not to e.g. round off numeric calculations to the nearest pixel.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Converting to int **from any value in any form** should simply give you the best guess of which integer is meant from the value. the string "5.0" is indeed an integer represented by a string, not a floating-point value. a decimal point doesn't make the difference, the value does. But besides that, I would even argue that the string "5.2" should give you an int of value 5. Because we mainly do these conversions to get to the right variable type to put into some function.

Answer (score 75):

`int` cannot convert an empty string to an integer. If the input string could be empty, consider either checking for this case:

```
if data:
    as_int = int(data)
else:
    # do something else
```

or using exception handling:

```
try:
    as_int = int(data)
except ValueError:
    # do something else
```

Comment: Your try/except doesn't distinguish between something reasonable expectable (blank/empty line) and something nasty like a non-integer.

Comment: and why would you want to distinguish those things?

Comment: because one is reasonably expectable and ignorable but the other is indicative of an error

Comment: and why is a blank line reasonably expectable and non-integer is not?

Comment: this is good if you are sure that your list is actually a list of stringified integers. If you are not sure you can do `n = int(line) if line.is_integer() else int(float(line))`

Answer (score 32):

Python will convert the number to a float. Simply calling float first then converting that to an int will work:
`output = int(float(input))`

Comment: Is this answer not equivalent to that given  by @FdoBad?

Answer (score 21):

This error occurs when trying to convert an empty string to an integer:

```
>>> int(5)
5
>>> int('5')
5
>>> int('')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Answer (score 13):

The reason is that you are getting an empty string or a string as an argument into int. Check if it is empty or it contains alpha characters. If it contains characters, then simply ignore that part.

Comment: This looks more like a comment.  When you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post.

Answer (score 12):

Given `floatInString = '5.0'`, that value can be converted to `int` like so:

```
floatInInt = int(float(floatInString))
```

Answer (score 3):

You've got a problem with this line:

```
while file_to_read != " ":
```

This does not find an empty string.  It finds a string consisting of one space.  Presumably this is not what you are looking for.

Listen to everyone else's advice.  This is not very idiomatic python code, and would be much clearer if you iterate over the file directly, but I think this problem is worth noting as well.

Comment: This is unrelated to the question being asked and which remains after proper editing. We see here the perils of failing to insist on [mre]s. Of course, standards were very different in 2009.

Answer (score 2):

My simple workaround to this problem was wrap my code in an `if` statement, taking advantage of the fact that an empty string [is not "truthy"](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/truthy-and-falsy-values-in-python/):

Given either of these two inputs:

```py
input_string = ""    # works with an empty string
input_string = "25"  # or a number inside a string
```

You can safely handle a blank string using this check:

```py
if input_string:
   number = int(input_string)
else:
   number = None # (or number = 0 if you prefer)

print(number)
```

Comment: This was already explained by existing answers, such as SilentGhost's.

Answer (score 1):

I recently came across a case where none of these answers worked. I encountered CSV data where there were null bytes mixed in with the data, and those null bytes did not get stripped. So, my numeric string, after stripping, consisted of bytes like this:

```
\x00\x31\x00\x0d\x00
```

To counter this, I did:

```
countStr = fields[3].replace('\x00', '').strip()
count = int(countStr)
```

...where fields is a list of csv values resulting from splitting the line.

Comment: The problem described here is effectively unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

This could also happen when you have to map space separated integers to a list but you enter the integers line by line using the `.input()`.
Like for example I was solving this problem on HackerRank [Bon-Appetit](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/bon-appetit/problem), and the got the following error while compiling
[image]

So instead of giving input to the program line by line try to map the space separated integers into a list using the `map()` method.

Comment: The underlying problem here is a different one; please see [Get a list of numbers as input from the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663306).

Answer (score 0):

This seems like readings is sometimes an empty string and obviously an error crops up.
You can add an extra check to your while loop before the **int(readings)** command like:

```
while readings != 0 or readings != '':
    readings = int(readings)
```

Answer (score 0):

your answer is throwing errors because of this line

```
readings = int(readings)
```

1. Here you are trying to convert a string into int type which is not base-10. you can convert a string into int only if it is base-10 otherwise it will throw ValueError, stating invalid literal for int() with base 10.

Answer (score 0):

Landed here as I had this problem but with `pandas` Dataframes. I had int values stored as `12345.0`.

The same solution applies in `pandas` (I believe it would work in `numpy` with `ndarrays` as well) :

```
df["my_int_value"] = df["my_string_value"].astype(float).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

This error sometimes shows up when changing the dtype of a pandas column using `astype(int)`. The `astype()` method raises `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''` for the very same reason that is detailed on many answers here.

In such cases, if you want the empty string `''` parsed as a missing value aka NaN, then use `to_numeric` instead of `astype()` and the error goes away.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['1', '2', '']})

df['col'] = df['col'].astype(int)      # ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

df['col'] = pd.to_numeric(df['col'])   # OK (the empty string is parsed as NaN)
```

Answer (score -1):

> I am creating a program that reads a
>   file and if the first line of the file
>   is not blank, it reads the next four
>   lines. Calculations are performed on
>   those lines and then the next line is
>   read.

Something like this should work:

```
for line in infile:
    next_lines = []
    if line.strip():
        for i in xrange(4):
            try:
                next_lines.append(infile.next())
            except StopIteration:
                break
    # Do your calculation with "4 lines" here
```

Answer (score -1):

Another answer in case all of the above solutions are not working for you.

My original error was similar to OP: *ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '52,002'*

I then tried the accepted answer and got this error: *ValueError: could not convert string to float: '52,002'* --this was when I tried the int(float(variable_name))

My solution is to convert the string to a float and leave it there. I just needed to check to see if the string was a numeric value so I can handle it correctly.

```py
try: 
   float(variable_name)
except ValueError:
   print("The value you entered was not a number, please enter a different number")
```

Comment: The problem description here does not make sense. Converting from float to int will not fail in ordinary cases, and is demonstrably not what failed in the examples. The underlying problem is that neither `int` nor `float` supports thousands separators by default. See [How can I convert a string with dot and comma into a float in Python](/questions/6633523) and [How to convert a string to a number if it has commas in it as thousands separators?](/questions/1779288).