# Python error in shell ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:

Tags: python, regex, shell, int

I am writing a program.  if short matches are mixed with longer matches. the program is to see which matches will fit back in the short  box.
This is my code:

```
import math
def q2():

    fin = open('input.txt','rt')
    fout = open('output.txt', 'wt')
    a= int(fin.readline().strip())
    b = [int(b) for b in str(a)]
    count = -1
    nMatches = b[0]
    width = b[1]
    heigth = b[2]
    length = width**2 + heigth**2
    length = length**(.5)
    while count <= nMatches:
        match = int(fin.readline().strip())
        count = count+ 1
        if match <= length:
            print('YES')
        else:
            print('NO')
```

This is the output:

```
YES
YES
YES
NO
NO
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    q2()
  File "D:/code/Q2/q2.py", line 15, in q2
    match = int(fin.readline().strip())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Thanks for any help
the content of fin is:
534
3
4
5
6
7

Comment: what is the content of `fin`?

Comment: Can you just print `match` and see what value you are getting ?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but does the exception not just show that he's trying to convert an empty string '' into an int? 10seconds for finding 4 sites to a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to convert an empty string to an int. But that's not possible.
Look at your exception: ... base 10: *''* <-- this is an empty string.

So you read a line, you strip it and then just an empty string is left. And that raises the ValueError

Here a stackoverflow answer (1 oder 2 result on google):
[ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841565/valueerror-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your loop count. Instead of using `while count < nMatches` why not just `for i in range(nMatches)`? Because your loop count is off, you're reading past the end of the file, which gives an error when you try to convert the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

I am making a lot of assumptions here because I don't know what is in the `fin` file. This is what I think you are trying to do:
`nMatches = 534` is the number of matches in the box.
`width = 3` and `height = 4` and somehow the that causes the `length` of the box to be 5

I am assuming that all the numbers after the first 3 in the `fin` file are the length of each match.

```
    from math import sqrt
    def q2():

    fin = open('text.txt','r')
    fout = open('output.txt', 'w')
    a = fin.readline().strip().split()
    b = [int(x) for x in a]
    nMatches = b[0]
    width = b[1]
    height = b[2]
    length = sqrt(width**2 + height**2)

    for match in b[3:]:

        if match <= length:
            print ('YES')
        else:
            print ('NO')

    q2()
```

This compares each number in the file to the length of the box.