# Invalid literal error for values from a list

Tags: python

I've checked other questions about this error but they look a bit different from what I'm trying to do, no direct user input for one thing so hope you can help.

Working with values in a grid I am trying to write code that works out the difference between two locations on the grid. Playerpos is the current position of a player, bossgroup represents a fixed point on the grid (or map) and is taken from a parallel map of bosses.

```
# playerposition, as row,column...
playerpos = [0,0]
a = playerpos[0]
b = playerpos[1]

# here I make it so the player can set a location in the bossmap
# as a fixed location called bossgroup. Build a HQ in game terms...
bossmap[playerpos[1]][playerpos[0]] = bossgroup
```

OR - there's a count value where the above statement is used if count is below the count value, but if above, `bossgroup` is created with the following statement. So far the invalid literal error always occurs below the count but I include both statements here just in case it's relevant.

```
# seems necessary to fomat bossgroup, to look like "1, 7" rather than "17"
bossgroup = str(a)+str(", ")+str(b)

# here coordinates are striped from the string describing bossgroup 
# and made into integers so math can be done....
c = int(bossgroup[0])
d = int(bossgroup[3])

# now i want to turn the differences between the two sets of row and columns in x and y values and do math to them, including using abs() to flip negs to positives
x = a - c
y = b - c
```

...

However the problem I have is I keep getting this error-

```
d = int(bossgroup[3])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Strangely, this doesn't always happen, it depends on the math stuff I do, but for now I think I've put enough code on the screen for your assistance, hope it is clear enough and sufficient to see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841565/valueerror-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10)

Comment: The empty string doesn't represent any integer. You need to figure out why `bossgroup[3]` is sometimes empty.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, thanks... not sure if '0' counts as empty... will have a play

Comment: `'0'` does not count as empty. It would be `0`. The `''` the error complains about is empty.

Comment: After all that code I splurted it was down to the empty value. Wood obscured by trees.

Answer (score 2):

Your error is clear and comes from these lines:

```
bossgroup = str(a)+str(", ")+str(b)
c = int(bossgroup[0])
d = int(bossgroup[3])
```

and happens when a is greater then 10. 
Example:
 *for a = 10 and b = 1* you will obtain *bossgroup = "10, 1"* , *c = int('1')* (which is the first character in bossgroup) and *d = int(' ')* (which is the thrird character in bossgroup) and that's your error, you cannot convert string to int.

The better way to compute the distance (difference) between two points a and b is to do this:

```
import math

d = math.sqrt( (b[0]-a[0])**2 + (b[1]-a[1])**2 )
```

Comment: Yep, if I make the distance greater than 10 the script does indeed crash. So if I understand correctly your way means I can do the same for variable 'c', and there's no need for x and y and no need to turn negative results into positives using abs()? 'd' will be the distance for row, 'c' the distance for column just as is?

Comment: `d = math.sqrt( (b[0]-a[0])**2 + (b[1]-a[1])**2 )` is just an example to compute the distance between 2 points. The a and b used in the formula are differents from those you use.  You can use this formula to compute the distance between 2 points in your grid. is that clear for you ?