# Using input for date python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a simple code in python 3 that shows you the day when you enter the month year and day. This is the code:

```
from datetime import date
s = date(2016, 4, 29).weekday()

if s == 0:
    print ("mon")
if s == 1:
    print ("tue")
if s == 2:
    print ("wed")
if s == 3:
    print ("thurs")
if s == 4:
    print ("fri")
if s == 5:
    print ("sat")
if s == 6:
    print ("sun")
```

The above code works, but I tried to do

```
from datetime import date
s = date(int(input())).weekday()
if s == 0:
    print ("mon")
if s == 1:
    print ("tue")
if s == 2:
    print ("wed")
if s == 3:
    print ("thurs")
if s == 4:
    print ("fri")
if s == 5:
    print ("sat")
if s == 6:
    print ("sun")
```

so I could let users enter their own day, but it gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "..\Playground\", line 2, in <module> 
    s = date(int(input())).weekday() 
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2016,'
```

I used the input 2016, 4, 29 if it helps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841565/valueerror-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10)

Comment: `2016, 4, 29` is not a valid integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
from datetime import date

usr_date = [int(x) for x in input().split(",")]
d = date(usr_date[0], usr_date[1], usr_date[2]).weekday()
print (d)
```

`datetime.date()` expects 3 integers but `input()` returns a string. This means that we have to:

- split the string returned by `input()` by comma to get three parts
- convert each part to an integer
- feed these parts to `datetime.date()`

This makes more sense, if you ask me:

```
from datetime import datetime

d = datetime.strptime(input(), '%Y,%m,%d').weekday()
print(d)
```

`datetime.strptime()` takes a string as input which is convenient because `input()` happens to return a string. This means that the splitting and casting/converting isn't necessary. You can find all the different date formats supported by `strptime()` in the [datetime docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).