# Python using int function

Tags: python, integer

I can't run the code below because of the 7th line `value = int(qty)*int(price)`. I can only run it if I use the `int()` function inside the `print()` function. Is there a way I can define it's an integer before I ask it to print? The same for **float**?

```
file = open("C:\\file.txt","r")
for mid in file:
    qty = mid[38:53]
    qty = qty.lstrip("0")
    price = mid[75:86]
    price = price.lstrip("0")
    value = int(qty)*int(price)
    trades = [qty,price,value]
    print (trades)
file.close()
```

Shell-->

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: You can always ask it to be an integer. The string you must be passing may contain letters which make the compiler think its a hexadecimal or have a "." making it a float

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841565/valueerror-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10)

Comment: You can ask for the type using type(var)

Comment: either qty or price are not something that can be converted to int. try to print them before the line `value = int(qty)*int(price)` to see whats inside.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that one of your items has either its price or quantity set to 0. When it's read in your code strips that 0 leaving you with an empty string, raising a ValueError when it is converted to an int.

You should probably remove the lstrips. At worst you will get numbers like "04" which the int constructor can handle anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The following function return the integer value or None in case the string is not valid integer:

```
def parseInt(ss):
    try:
        return int(ss)
    except:
        return None
```

Use this function to check if the string is an integer:

```
for mid in file:
    qty = mid[38:53]
    qty = qty.lstrip("0")
    qty = parseInt(qty)

    price = mid[75:86]
    price = price.lstrip("0")
    price = parseInt(price)

    if qty != None and price != None:
        value = qty*price
        trades = [qty,price,value]
        print (trades)
file.close()
```