# Why is Python throwing a ValueError for what appears to be a valid string for int()?

Tags: python-2.7, integer, radix

Why is this happening?:

```
>>> int('20', 3)
6
>>> int('8', 3)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
    int('8', 3)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 3: '8'
```

Yes, I have seen this post: [ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841565/valueerror-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10)

But '8' does not have any decimals. Nor does it have any whitespace. Why isn't this working? Surely 8 is possible to represent in base 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why isn't this working?

Because 8 is invalid integer in base 3. Base 3 only allows integers from 0 (inclusive), to 2 (exclusive), thus causing the `ValueError`.

> Surely 8 is possible to represent in base 3.

Yes, but that's not what `int()` does. It converts a representation to a number.

```
>>> int('22', 3)
8
```

As seen above, `int` takes *in* a number in the specified base, them converts it to an integer.