# How to convert a date range object to an integer in Python

Tags: python-3.x, loops, iteration

I am trying to iterate over a single column 'YEAR'in a dataframe which has objects that appear like "1998" and "2006-2008". For the second example, I would like to convert those to an integer average value between the two like "2007". How should I go about doing this?

Comment: And for something like `2006-2007`, what would you want? Or does that never happen?

Comment: Any code you have written?

Comment: I would prefer to round to the nearest integer in the case of a decimal.

Comment: I am trying to implement this code I found on a different post by @petermortenson here [basic links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841565/valueerror-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10)
`h = open(fname)
for line in h:
    if line.strip():
        [int(next(h).strip()) for _ in range(4)]     # list of integers`

Answer (score 0):

```
import arrow

def date_to_int(value):
    time_zone_diff = 8 * 60 * 60
    return arrow.get(value).timestamp - time_zone_diff
```