# Why does int(float(str)) work but int(str) not work

Tags: python, type-conversion, int

Suppose I have a string:

```
temp = "0.1"
```

When I run `int(temp)`:

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0.1'
```

But when I run `int(float(temp))`:

I get the correct output i.e. `0`

---

**Why does converting to `float` and then converting to `int` work but directly converting to `int` not work ?**

Thanks and regards

Comment: Because the value in the string **is not** an integer variable, it's a `floating-point` variable.

Comment: @Azhy But the value in float(temp) is also a floating-point variable

Comment: Yes but it's in a string not currently floating-point var.

Comment: @Azhy Ahhh... now I get it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841565/valueerror-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10)

Comment: I see you haven't accepted any of the answers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because your string has float format. So when you directly cast "0.1" to int, it returns a error. But if you cast to float and after to int, it is able to truncate your number.

Comment: But why can't it truncate a string directly

Comment: Because, int() doesn't recognize "0.1" as a number.

Comment: But, in this case, float() recognizes.

Comment: But int can recognize float("0.1") as a number ?

Comment: Yes, because float() transforms this string to a number, and after int() truncates it get only the integer part.

Answer (score 4):

This is [documented](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) behaviour (emphasis mine):

> If `x` is a number, it can be a plain integer, a long integer, or a floating point number. If `x` is floating point, the conversion ***truncates towards zero***.
>
> If `x` is not a number or if `base` is given, then `x` must be a string or Unicode object ***representing an integer literal*** in radix `base`

So as to your question *why*, the only answer is: because it is like that by design.

Answer (score 2):

From the python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#int)

> If x is not a number or if base is given, then x must be a string, bytes, or bytearray instance representing an integer literal in radix base. Optionally, the literal can be preceded by + or - (with no space in between) and surrounded by whitespace. A base-n literal consists of the digits 0 to n-1, with a to z (or A to Z) having values 10 to 35. The default base is 10. The allowed values are 0 and 2–36. Base-2, -8, and -16 literals can be optionally prefixed with 0b/0B, 0o/0O, or 0x/0X, as with integer literals in code.

**then x must be a string, bytes, or bytearray instance representing an integer**
So if you add a `.` to the string it won't represent an integer anymore

Answer (score 1):

If you pass a string to `int`, it only works if the string directly represents an integer.  It doesn't work if the string represents a non-integer number.  But if you pass a float to `int`, it always works, by truncating the float.  `int` just doesn't accept "strings that could be made into ints by first making them into floats and then truncating them"; it only accepts strings that directly represent integers.  That's just how `int` works.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that numeric objects like floats have a special `__int__` or `__trunc__` method which computes their integer value while strings are parsed. See [int()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) in the docs.

Thus the result of `int(0.1)` comes from the `O.1` object and the result of `int("0.1")` comes from the `int()` function.