# python mapreduce - average

Tags: python, mapreduce, key, average

Python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#Reducer.py
import sys

age_balance = {}

#Partitoner
for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()
    age, balance = line.split('\t')

    if age in age_balance:
        age_balance[age].append(int(balance))
    else:
        age_balance[age] = []
        age_balance[age].append(int(balance))

#Reducer
for age in age_balance.keys():
    ave_age = sum(age_balance[age])*1.0 / len(age_balance[age])
    print '%s\t%s'% (age, ave_age)
```

Hi I'm receiving an error:
File "C:\Code\study\reducer.py", line 16, in  age_balance[balance].append(int(age)) ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '"age"'
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.

[This is a sample of the data im trying to get average of :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wt1xt.png)

Comment: Do you have word **"age"** in the header of input file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841565/valueerror-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10)

Comment: @AntoJurković yes I have the word age should i remove it?

Comment: You can remove it or skip it in your script.Otherwise, that line is parsed and provided as input to `int()`. And as the result you got `ValueError`