# Finding sum of rows from CSV files with header

Tags: python

Need to find the average of scores of the user when user inputs the gamer id

The csv file:

> name      tribe     id    Score1 Score2 Score3  Score4
>     Aang      Normad   N321B   89     67     54      78
>
> Gyatso    Omaticay O111C  54      78     65      54

i tried adding in some stuff I found on SO, but got the error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Score1'. Will appreciate anyone that can point me in the right direction, just began learning python.

```
import  csv
filePath="data.csv"


with open(filePath) as csvfile:
    avatar_id=  input ("Enter Avatar ID:")    
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)  
    for row in reader:
        if avatar_id in row['id']:
        #just print some stuff
            user,tribe,id, *scores= row 
            average= sum([int(score) for score in scores])/4
              print("{0:>6}{1:>8}{2:>7}{3:>7}{4:^14}".format(row['Air'],row['Water'],row['Earth'],row['Fire'], average))
            print("==============================") 
        else:
            x=5
if x>4:
    print('No avatar found')
```

Comment: possible dup : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841565/valueerror-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10

Comment: `user,tribe,id, *scores= row` should be `user,tribe,id, *scores= row.values()`. If you'd put a simple `print(row)` on every iteration, you would see that `row`s are dicts. I'm flagging the question as a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error tells you exactly what the problem is. Your code is trying to convert the header label `Score1` to an integer in this line:

```
average= sum([int(score) for score in scores])/4
```

and failing. To avoid including the header labels in the computation, test `reader.line_num` to skip the first line of the file.

Or, to be safe, just ignore any non_numeric data:

```
if all(score.isdigit() for score in scores):
    average= sum([int(score) for score in scores])/4
```

Comment: is there any ways I can skip the header with csv files?

Comment: Well, I suggested that you test `reader.line_num` but I've put in an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
*scores= row
```

with

```
scores = row['Score1']+row['Score2']+row['Score3']+row['Score4']
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an extra check for not existent keys and remove empty rows in your CSV file. You also need to add delimiter to your csv.DictReader as it defaults to comma separator. See example bellow:

```
import  csv
import io
filePath="""name tribe id Score1 Score2 Score3 Score4
Aang Normad N321B 89 67 54 78
Gyatso Omaticay O111C 54 78 65 54
"""

avatar_id=  input ("Enter Avatar ID:")    
reader = csv.DictReader(io.StringIO(filePath),delimiter=' ')  
for row in reader:
    print(row)
    if avatar_id in row.get('id',''):
        user,tribe,id, *scores= row.values()
        average= sum([int(score) for score in scores])/4
        print("==============================") 
        break
    else:
        x=None
if x is None:
    print('No avatar found')
else:
    print("{} score is {}".format(avatar_id,x))
```