# How to create a circle with given radius in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

What I want to do is create a circle using `create_oval()` with the radius `r` entered in `Entry()` widget. I don't understand what the problem is. Here's my code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

#Drawing the circle
def circle(canvas,x,y,r):
   id = canvas.create_oval(x-r,y-r,x+r,y+r)
   return id


#Label
radiusLabel = Label(root, text="Enter the radius: ")
radiusLabel.grid(row=0,column=0)


#Entering the radius
radiusEntry = Entry(root)
radiusEntry.grid(row=1, column=0)


r = int(radiusEntry.get())

#Canvas 
canvas = Canvas(width=400,height=400, bg="#cedbd2")
canvas.grid(row=2,column=0)


#Calling the function for drawing the circle button
radiusButton = Button(root, text="Create",command=circle(canvas,100,100,r))
radiusButton.grid(row=2,column=1)

root.mainLoop()
```

Here's the output and the console:
[image]

Comment: While not causing the .get() error, radiumButton.grid(row=2,column=1) should probably be radiusButton

Comment: @EugeneProut Ah, that should be Radius, Ill edit it now, it is like that in my code.

Comment: First you have to understand [Event-driven programming](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9343402/7414759) Does this answer your question? [valueerror-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841565)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter "command" takes a pointer to a function, not a function itself so you cannot call it like that, also, when you first run the program, `get()` returns an empty string thus causing the invalid literal error you are getting, you need to call it when your button is clicked, e.g.:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

#Label
radiusLabel = Label(root, text="Enter the radius: ")
radiusLabel.grid(row=0,column=0)


#Entering the radius
radiusEntry = Entry(root)
radiusEntry.grid(row=1, column=0)

#Canvas 
canvas = Canvas(width=400,height=400, bg="#cedbd2")
canvas.grid(row=2,column=0)

#Drawing the circle
def circle():
    x=100
    y=100
    r = 0
    if radiusEntry.get():
        r = int(radiusEntry.get())
    id = canvas.create_oval(x-r,y-r,x+r,y+r)
    return id

#Calling the function for drawing the circle button
radiusButton = Button(root, text="Create", command=circle)
radiusButton.grid(row=2,column=1)


root.mainloop()
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah, I get it now, Thank You so much!