# ValueError Exception handling in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I want to handle ValueError in Python. But whenever I type the below code I get an error and I want the output as I excepted.

```
a, b = map(int, input().split())
try:
    print(a//b)
except ZeroDivisionError as e:
    print('Enter code: ', e)
except ValueError as e:
    print('Enter code: ', e)
```

If my inputs for a and b are '1' and '$' than
Expected output for ValueError: 'Enter code: invalid literal for int() with base 10: $

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841565/valueerror-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is before your `try`, here `a, b = map(int, input().split())`

The `$` is given to `int`, this fails and raise the `invalid literal for int() with base 10: $` which is pretty explicit

```
try:
    a, b = map(int, input().split())
    print(a//b)
except ZeroDivisionError as e:
    print('Enter code: ', e)
except ValueError as e:
    print('Enter code: ', e)
```

Comment: Thanks, it really helped me

Comment: @ShivManoharlalSharma Think about reading the Exception, they are helpful ;)

Comment: @ShivManoharlalSharma You can now think about [accepting the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)