# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' What is wrong

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a project where I have to create a Mean, Median, Mode, and Range calculator and I keep failing to get the number from the user as input. Here's the code:

```
print("Mean, Median, Mode, and Range Calculator")
user_input = input("Press 1 to choose Mean , 2 to choose Median, 3 to choose Mode, and 4 to choose Range")

def get_num():
    x = [input("Enter your numbers Without commas ie. 12 34 56: ")]
    x1 = []
    for i in x: 
        x1.append(int(i)) 
        print(x1)


if user_input == '1':
    pass
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '12 34 56'
```

I've tried using a map, using for to loop through the list but it doesn't work. I don't even know what the error means can someone explain?

Comment: you want to x.split()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841565/valueerror-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10)

Comment: You shouldn't put `input()` inside a list.

Comment: Yep, just use the `input()` to get the numbers and then apply `split()` and you'll get an iterable `list`and you´ll be able to use `for` loop

Answer (score 2):

Try this.
Also `user_input` is undefined. if you're using `x1` just to convert to `int` then you don't need it. `map` does that for you.

```
def get_num():
    x = map(int,input("Enter your numbers Without commas ie. 12 34 56: ").split())
    return x


x1 = []
x = get_num()
for i in x:
    x1.append(i)
    print(x1)
```

Comment: just ``split()`` is equivalent of ``split(" ")``

Answer (score 1):

Don't put the call to `input()` inside a list. To get a list of the words that were entered, use `split()`.

```
def get_num():
    x = input("Enter your numbers Without commas ie. 12 34 56: ")
    x1 = []
    for i in x.split(): 
        x1.append(int(i)) 
    print(x1)
```

You can also use a list comprehension.

```
def get_num():
    x = input("Enter your numbers Without commas ie. 12 34 56: ")
    x1 = [x1.append(int(i)) for i in x.split()]
    print(x1)
```

Answer (score 0):

A nice way is to use a `map` to convert the `input` to `int` and use `list` function to wrap the `map`.

```
def get_num():
    x = input("Enter your numbers Without commas ie. 12 34 56: ")
    x1 = list(map(lambda i: int(i), x.split()))
    print(x1)
```