# Creating a list with specific values from a list of dictionaries (keys as strings and values are list of integers)

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries with a string and a list of strings as values for their respective keys:

```
list_of_dictionaries = [
    {'id': 'ABBA', 'num': ['10', '3', '5', '1']},
    {'id': 'ABAC', 'num': ['4', '5', '6', '20']}]
```

Each letter in the 'id' string corresponds with the number in 'num' at matching indices. So for value 'ABBA' it would match the value in 'num' at each position in order: A = 10, B = 3, B = 5, A = 1. I would  like return a list of the ids with 'num' > 5 in each dictionary while maintaining their current order.

Here is my attempt:

```
bad_values = ['','0','1','2','3','4','5']
final_ids =[]
for i in list_of_dictionaries:
     list_of_high_num =[]
     for id,num in enumerate(i.items()):
          if i["num"] is not bad_values:
             list_of_high_num.append(i["id"])
        final_ids.append(list_of_high_num)
```

However, I'm just getting my original string of ids back in a list. Where am I going wrong?

Desired output something like this:

```
final_list = [['A'], ['A', 'C']]
```

Comment: What's your expected output? You need to provide a [mre]. BTW, welcome to SO! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want more advice.

Comment: Can you provide an example output for your program and a more clear explanation of the algorithm? Doesn't make sense to me....

Comment: What do you think `if i["num"] is not bad_values:` is doing? This will always return `False`.

Comment: Edited with my desired output. Thank you for providing those intro resources, obviously I am new and new to Python.

Comment: With if i["num"] is not bad_values: I am say I want all of the values that are higher than 5. I tried using i["num"] > 5: but this causes issues because I get a TypeError. From my searching, I think the i.items() is returning a tuple which causes this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

considering the scenario for each `dictionary` item `len(id) = len(num)`

```
list_of_dictionaries = [
    {'id': 'ABBA', 'num': ['10', '3', '5', '1']},
    {'id': 'ABAC', 'num': ['4', '5', '6', '20']}]

limit = 5

outerlist = []
for d in list_of_dictionaries:
    innerlist = []
    for x in range(len(d['num'])):
        if int(d['num'][x]) > limit:
            innerlist.append(d['id'][x])
    outerlist.append(innerlist)

print(outerlist) # [['A'], ['A', 'C']]
```

Comment: Please test this with all your inputs and share if any error.

Comment: It works with the smaller example! However, I'm getting ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''. There are a few places for which 'num': [''], as there is missing data I think that's the issue.

Comment: ```invalid literal for int() with base 10:``` you get this when you have a empty string.  For example ```int('')``` Check your inputs again. If all are of equal length.

Comment: ```invalid literal for int() with base 10:``` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841565/valueerror-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10

Comment: Yes, it turns out I had some weird additional spaces in the data set, which created empty strings in the way I parsed the data set. The code works perfectly now that it's fixed. Thank you so much!