# How can we numerically filter a dataframe based on multiple conditions if there are strings in one of the columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to filter a data frame based on two conditions.

1. filter items where the field named 'Count' > 30
   ...and...
2. filter items where the field named 'LAND SQUARE FEET' < 5000

Here is the code that I tried, and I got errors, or I wouldn't be posting here.

```
df.loc[(df['Count']>=30) & (df['LAND SQUARE FEET']< 5000)['Count','LAND SQUARE FEET']]

df[df.eval("Count>=30 & (LAND SQUARE FEET <5000).values")]
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Hi @ASH it's always helpful to post the error message you are receiving into your question.

Comment: I think you missed a comma. Try: `df.loc[(df['Count']>=30) & (df['LAND SQUARE FEET']< 5000),['Count','LAND SQUARE FEET']]`

Comment: A [sample df](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) also helps!

Comment: @ASH did this work for you? Kindly accept as solution and upvote if helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df[(df["Count"] >= 30) & (df["LAND SQUARE FEET"] < 5000)]
```

Comment: the OP is also trying to filter by specific columns in addition to rows. Also, code only answers are not considered good answers.

Comment: @DavidErickson My bad. Kinda new to posting here. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @Kevin: I think your solution is very close, and this is interesting...apparently the 'Land Square Feet' is of object data type.  I tried this: df["LAND SQUARE FEET"] = df["LAND SQUARE FEET"].astype(str).astype(int)

I got this error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' -  '

Comment: I would suggest doing .astype(str).astype(float) as suggested by this stackoverflow answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47764450/14102346

Comment: @ASH you have a string in your dataframe. I'll post a solution to show how to handle that.

Answer (score 1):

Specifically, the error(see comments of other answer) is now saying there is a `-` in one of the values in your column, You can use my solution below OR you can do `df["LAND SQUARE FEET"] = df["LAND SQUARE FEET"] =.replace('-','').astype(int)` However, there may be other strings that you need to replace, that might mean you keep seeing errors if there are more strings, other than `-`, for example `,` or `ft.`. Also, that line with `-` might be bad data altogether as I'm not sure why a `-` would be in a number that is supposed to be an integer of square feet.

Also, you can look at that line specifically with `df[df["LAND SQUARE FEET"].str.contains('-')` and from there decide what you want to do with it -- either manipulate it's data with `replace` or make it `NaN` with `pd.to_numeric()`

---

**Solution with `pd.to_numeric()`:**

You need to use `pd.to_numeric()` first as you have strings in your column and passing `errors='coerce'` changes to `NaN` for those values that are strings. The data type of the column should now be a `float` if you call `df.info()`:

Step 1:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"LAND SQUARE FEET" : [4500, '4,400 feet', '4,600', 4700, 5500, 6000],
                   "Count" : [45,55,65,75,15,25]})
df
Out[1]: 
  LAND SQUARE FEET  Count
0             4500     45
1       4,400 feet     55
2            4,600     65
3             4700     75
4             5500     15
5             6000     25
```

---

Step 2:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"LAND SQUARE FEET" : [4500, '4,400 feet', '4,600', 4700, 5500, 6000],
                   "Count" : [45,55,65,75,15,25]})
df["LAND SQUARE FEET"] = pd.to_numeric(df["LAND SQUARE FEET"], errors='coerce')
df
Out[2]: 
   LAND SQUARE FEET  Count
0            4500.0     45
1               NaN     55
2               NaN     65
3            4700.0     75
4            5500.0     15
5            6000.0     25
```

---

Step 3 (and final output):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"LAND SQUARE FEET" : [4500, '4,400 feet', '4,600', 4700, 5500, 6000],
                   "Count" : [45,55,65,75,15,25]})
df["LAND SQUARE FEET"] = pd.to_numeric(df["LAND SQUARE FEET"], errors='coerce')
new_df = df.loc[(df['Count']>=30) & (df['LAND SQUARE FEET']< 5000),['Count','LAND SQUARE FEET']]
new_df
Out[3]: 
   Count  LAND SQUARE FEET
0     45            4500.0
3     75            4700.0
```