# Getting user input error when in app form

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, runtime-error

I am trying to convert a python program file into an app, following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z7SuwNos6XY).

My program needs to take the user input, however:

```
 print("What DOMAIN do you want to block?")
 print("Example: youtube.com")
 websitebeingblocked = input()
```

When I run my program, it prints out:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10
```

I tried following the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841565/valueerror-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10), but my program still doesn't work. I think it went wrong when I asked for user input - how can I solve this?

Please please help me; I still have not found a solution. Even a comment would really help!

Comment: You tagged this post python 3.x, but it looks like that error is because you are using python 2.

Comment: What do you mean by "converting a program to an app". What do you mean by a program versus an app? Also, please post the full stacktrace, as well as your Python version.

Comment: @RandomDavis In can in python2, because `input()` in python2 is the same as `eval(input())` in python3

Comment: @jordanm really? I use python 3 in idle. How do I make it parse the program as python 3?

Comment: @jordanm or should I just replace it with eval(input())  ?

Comment: For python2 you want `raw_input()` instead of `input()`, but using py2 is not recommended because it's been EOL for a year now

Comment: so for python 3 should I just use eval(input()) ?

Comment: "I think it went wrong when I asked for user input" - I'm not convinced. Did you see any of the print statements before the input? I skimmed through that tutorial video and it is using python2.7. I am not sure what it is doing to your python code to make it an executable but it is quite possible that something it "adds" is generating that error. Try creating a new ultra simple "Hello World" program and run that through the "convert to exe" process and check it works or (more likely) if you get the same error.

Comment: OH! I didn't notice it was Python 2.7! That's probably what's causing the error. Thank you!! Do you mind writing that as an answer so I can close this question?