# Error converting shape to a TensorShape when loading model in flask

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask, model, pythonanywhere

I trained a CNN model in a local machine, saved the model using `model.save('./models/my_model')` and I am able to load the model `(new_model = tensorflow.keras.models.load_model('./models/my_model'))` and classify an image that I pass through a browser by using the web framework Flask.

Now, I want to run my code hosted in pythonanywhere.com. However, when loading the model I got this error:

> ValueError: Error converting shape to a TensorShape: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'class_name'.

I don't know if has to do with versions. First I trained with python 3.8 and the latest tensorflow version, but since Flask does not allow all the required libraries in 3.8, I used 3.7 in flask with tensorflow 2.0.0. So I retrained the model in my computer with 3.7 and tf 2.0.0 and uploaded the newer model files. However, the same error persists.

--update--
I put here the log error

> Error running WSGI application
> ValueError: Error converting shape to a TensorShape: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'class_name'.

> File "/var/www/user_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 16, in 
> from main import app as application  # noqa

> File "/home/user/mysite/main.py", line 11, in 
> model = tensorflow.keras.models.load_model('/home/user/mysite/models/modelo')

> File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/save.py", line 150, in load_model
> return saved_model_load.load(filepath, compile)

> File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py", line 86, in load
> model = tf_load.load_internal(path, loader_cls=KerasObjectLoader)

> File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/saved_model/load.py", line 541, in load_internal
> export_dir)

> File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py", line 103, in **init**
> self._finalize()

> File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py", line 127, in _finalize
> node.add(layer)

> File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/tracking/base.py", line 457, in _method_wrapper
> result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)

> File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 174, in add
> batch_shape=batch_shape, dtype=dtype, name=layer.name + '_input')

> File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/input_layer.py", line 263, in Input
> input_tensor=tensor)

> File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/input_layer.py", line 125, in **init**
> ragged=ragged)

> File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/backend.py", line 1057, in placeholder
> x = array_ops.placeholder(dtype, shape=shape, name=name)

> File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 2630, in placeholder
> return gen_array_ops.placeholder(dtype=dtype, shape=shape, name=name)

> File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 6669, in placeholder
> shape = _execute.make_shape(shape, "shape")

> File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/execute.py", line 211, in make_shape
> e))

The error comes from a tensorflow file, and I am just passing the path where is the saved model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TensorFlow is not currently working in PythonAnywhere web apps. If you're using Keras, you can try switching to Theano backend which is confirmed to work. There's a short [help page](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/MachineLearningInWebsiteCode/) on that as well.

Answer (score -2):

Python has a problem converting your `class_name` to int.

Refer to : [ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841565/valueerror-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10)

Comment: The error comes from a tensorflow file. I am just using a tensorflow function for loading a saved model (with tensorflow) which works fine in my local machine. The proposals in the link are using float or reading the file properly, however, I can't modify the tensorflow library functions to do so.