# What does this Exception in Tkinter callback mean and also what is the "template" for creating a tkinter input box?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am 15 and very new to coding. I am creating an application that involves taking data from a box and inputting it into the code. I also do not know what this callback means. Any input helps!

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Micha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 1895, in **call**
return self.func(*args)
File "C:/Users/Micha/PycharmProjects/restartebaybot/main.py", line 56, in startbot
timeing = int(input(self.box2.get()))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841565/valueerror-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10)

Comment: Please format your code. See [How do I format code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361)

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: `int("")` will give you that error.

Answer (score 0):

Invalid literal for int () with base 10 error is raised when you try to convert a string value that is not formatted as an integer. To solve this problem, you can use the float () method to convert a floating-point number in a string to an integer. Then, you can use int () to convert your number to an integer.

***Edit:***

For example, if you run this code:

`print(int("python") + 3)`

You get this error:

`ValueError: Invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'python'`

Now you may be able to understand it. In case you don't, please edit your question and add the code that gave the error.

Comment: Could you please expand on this?