# Python error - Invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a newbie to Python and can't wrap my head around this one. I have a python script which takes in 2 arguments from user. Below is the code -

```
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import time
import csv
import collections
import argparse

MyVar1 = range(1,11)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('Hrs', help='Enter the hours', type=int)
parser.add_argument('Mins', help='Enter the minutes', type=int)
parser.parse_args()

class TimeTesting:
    def __init__(self, Hours, Minutes):
        self.Hours = Hours
        self.Minutes = Minutes

    def TimeTest1(self):
        self.T1 = datetime.datetime.now()
        time.sleep(1)
        StopTime = self.T1 + timedelta(hours=int(self.Hours)) + timedelta(minutes=int(self.Minutes))
        print('{}'.format(StopTime.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')))

    def TimeTest2(self):
        self.T2 = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.TimeDiff = self.T2 - self.T1
        print('Timetest2 function called')


ob = TimeTesting('Hrs', 'Mins')

for item in MyVar1:
    ob.TimeTest1()
    ob.TimeTest2()
```

This is how I am calling the function from command line.

**`cmd> MyScript.py 1 30`**

Below is the error which I am getting.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\MyScript.py",
> line 37, in 
> ob.TimeTest1()   File "C:\Users\MyScript.py",
> line 25, in TimeTest1
> StopTime = self.T1 + timedelta(hours=int(self.Hours)) + timedelta(minutes=int(self.Minutes)) ValueError: invalid literal for
> int() with base 10: 'Hrs'

I am not sure if I am passing the arguments to the class object **`ob`** correctly. I have looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841565/valueerror-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10) but could not find any solution to my problem.

Comment: "Hrs" is a string, you need to pass in values for the timespan i.e `1` and `30`

Comment: More specifically, you need to [do something with the args](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) when you receive them

Comment: @Sayse - I am doing that while calling the script from command line. `MyScript.py 1 30`

Comment: Right, but then you dont do anything with what the user gives you, the `Hrs` and `"Mins"` you provide to creating an instance of your class are the literal strings, not the users input

Comment: @Sayse - You are right. I totally didn't realise that until now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `parser.parse_args()` doesn't really do anything (well, it does *something*, but it has no effect). You want to actually ***save*** those parsed arguments, like:

```
args = parser.parse_args()
```

and then pass the actual arguments from the command-line instead of literal strings:

```
ob = TimeTesting(args.Hrs, args.Mins)
```

Also note that those arguments are already defined with `type=int`, so the `int()` conversion inside the class is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Change to next two lines:

```
args = parser.parse_args()
....
ob = TimeTesting(args.Hrs, args.Mins)
```

Full working code:

[Try it online!](https://replit.com/@moytrage/StackOverflow66763321#main.py)

```
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import time
import csv
import collections
import argparse

MyVar1 = range(1,11)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('Hrs', help='Enter the hours', type=int)
parser.add_argument('Mins', help='Enter the minutes', type=int)
args = parser.parse_args()

class TimeTesting:
    def __init__(self, Hours, Minutes):
        self.Hours = Hours
        self.Minutes = Minutes

    def TimeTest1(self):
        self.T1 = datetime.datetime.now()
        time.sleep(1)
        StopTime = self.T1 + timedelta(hours=int(self.Hours)) + timedelta(minutes=int(self.Minutes))
        print('{}'.format(StopTime.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')))

    def TimeTest2(self):
        self.T2 = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.TimeDiff = self.T2 - self.T1
        print('Timetest2 function called')


ob = TimeTesting(args.Hrs, args.Mins)

for item in MyVar1:
    ob.TimeTest1()
    ob.TimeTest2()
```

Input:

```
python test.py 1 30
```

Output:

```
2021/03/23 17:15:36
Timetest2 function called
2021/03/23 17:15:37
Timetest2 function called
2021/03/23 17:15:38
Timetest2 function called
2021/03/23 17:15:39
Timetest2 function called
2021/03/23 17:15:40
Timetest2 function called
2021/03/23 17:15:41
Timetest2 function called
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you use

ob = TimeTesting('Hrs', 'Mins')

so the attribute `self.Hours` of the object `ob` will have the value `'Hrs'` (a string), which cannot be converted to an `int` in the later part of the code `int(self.Hours)`.

You probably need to pass differenct values when creating the object `ob`, or add some error checking before doing calculations.

Comment: What you have mentioned in your answer makes sense and is probably correct. But unfortunately that's not the solution to my problem. Thank you for sharing your valuable inputs.