# Pycharm including \n with multiple lines of input()

Tags: python, pycharm

```
x = int(input())
y = int(input())
print(x + y)
```

In running code online, using 2 input() like the one above automatically excludes the \n. The code  when ran in pycharm
does not run anything, instead it gets an error because it includes \n inside the input().
Is there a way to configure the settings to fix this? If not, is there any text editor that someone would recommend for a beginner who will solve simple coding problems or should I just stick to running code online?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "pycharm [..] includes \n inside the input()"? If you run this code and enter text on the console, no `\n` will be included in the values of `x` and `y`

Comment: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '5\n5' is the error message

Comment: Try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1841607) to strip the EOL `\n` from the input before passing it as an argument to `int()`.

Answer (score 0):

### Updated:

you need to remove non-digit with regex

```py
import re
y = int(''.join(re.findall(r'\d+', input())))
x = int(''.join(re.findall(r'\d+', input())))
print(x + y)
```

or if you want to avoid regex you can do it by looping over your string, char by char, and chack witch one is a digit

```py
y = int(''.join(ch for ch in input() if ch.isdigit()))
x = int(''.join(ch for ch in input() if ch.isdigit()))
print(x + y)
```

Comment: We are given machine problems in class and when I copy paste the sample input it include \n in the input is my problem

Comment: are you on linux, or mac?

Comment: I run on windows 11, is that the answer you were looking for? The thing is I have been solving problems in hackerrank all this time and I would want to solve offline. in hackerrank when you have input() on 2 separate lines, and have custom input separated by a newline it automatically separates the input

Comment: oh i think i got your problem, your are pasting a value that has a `5\n` in it

Comment: Yes, To make it work, I have to press 5, enter then 5 enter to separate, in hackerrank it kinda gets the input in one go. is this a limitation of pycharm itself or are there settings for it is my question

Comment: updated answer, let me know if it solve your problem

Comment: It doesn't work sorry (when I input 5 then shift enter 5, the value inside the x is 55 and the program waits for a 2nd input before it successfully runs, i als dont want to try and add some imports because we are submitting machine problem solutions online like hackerrank, it looks like its a limitation of pycharm? Where do people usually solve problems in competitive programming?

Comment: why you press shift enter?

Comment: when i pres shift enter it show me a popup `This view is read-only`

Comment: to get to the new line, most problems we encounter is separated by new line,  or either I copy-paste the sample input (separated by a new line) in hackerrank the problem does not automatically run and still waits for the 2nd input because it somehow concatenated the 1st input

Comment: so how about you have 1 `input()` and you split the string by `\n`??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237862/discussion-between-supermage1-and-flaxon).