# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' || lst.append(int(input()))

Tags: python, valueerror

Why do I get this error?

and its output:

```py
lst.append(int(input()))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

```py
lst = []
for n in range(n):
    lst.append(int(input()))
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841565/valueerror-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10
Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: What do you enter? Please, post [mre], incl. full traceback you get. It looks you just hit Enter

Comment: error means you try to convert empty string - `int("")` - maybe you should first get `input()`, next check if it not empty, and next convert to `int` and put on list. But you may have similar problem when you input text i.e. `Hello` instead of string with number. And maybe it would be to use `try/except` to catch error when it tries to convert `int("")` or `int("Hello")`

Answer (score 2):

The error is given because you are pressing enter, sending an empty string `''` to the `input()`, which cannot be interpreted as an int.

Also its probably a good idea  to change first `n` in `for n in range(n)` with something else.

Comment: @Kelly edited. At first I thought it would cause incorrect number of iterations, which may have caused the invalid input. Then I realized `range(n)` gets calculated once and after that `n` variable can freely be used within the loop if needed.

Answer (score -1):

Probably because you're inputting something that's not an int.

Your `int(input())` tries to convert its type to int, so if you're typing 'hello' or 5.154 it will fail.

You can just leave `lst.append(input())`  to get any value as string or `lst.append(float(input()))` if you're inputting a float number.