# Hello I am currently facing this Error on my program. I tried many stfuff like the map solution. ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:

Tags: python

```
student_heights = input("Input a list of student heights ").split(" ,")
student_heights = list(map(int, student_heights))

total_heights=0
for heights in student_heights:
    total_heights+=heights

num_of_students=0

for students in student_heights:
    num_of_students+=1

average= total_heights / num_of_students
print(round(average))
```

Comment: What's your question? Please add more details

Comment: What input are you entering?

Comment: Please post the full error message, including the traceback, in the question body. Paste it as text and put it inside a code block.

Comment: Maybe you tried to input a floating number?  See here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841565/     To get quick help, it's better to provide the exact *input* next time.

Answer (score 0):

student_heights = input("Input a list of student heights ").split(" ,")
thats because you have space split(" ,") here u just need .split(",")