# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'C' , Where is the conversion from string into integer happening?

Tags: python, list

I have reviewed similar [errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841565/valueerror-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10). It seems that somewhere in my code I am converting a string into integer. But I do not know where.

I have an input list 'ops', which contains strings. I also have another list 'record' that I am filling up with integers.

```
def baseball_game (ops):
  record = []
  for i in range (len(ops)):
    if ops[i] == 'C': 
      record.pop()   #I remove last element. I am mot converting into integer.
      print(record)
    if ops[i] == 'D':
      record.append(record[-1] * 2)  #I am doubling the value of last element, which is already an integer.
      print(record)
    if ops[i] == '+':
      record.append(record[-1] + record[-2]) #I am adding last 2 elements, which are NOT integers.
      print(record)
    else:
      record.append(int(ops[i])) #I am converting into integer any value which is NOT 'C', 'D' nor '+'
      print(record)
  return sum(record)
```

[image]

Comment: You're missing `else` in your `if`s... so the code will continue after the check for `C`

Comment: You are calling `int()` on any character other than `+`.  The tests for `C` and `D` are standalone `if` statements, they have no connection to the `else` in question.  The pattern you need here is `if` / `elif` / `elif` / `else`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have 3 `if` blocks in a row, and you are expecting them to behave like `elif`s.

When `ops[i]` is `'C'`, it enters the first `if` block, and then, because `'C' != '+'`, it enters the `else` block at the end.

Comment: You are right. I changed 2 "if" into "elif", and it worked.