# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '198.217.121.0'

Tags: python-3.10

Hey i am trying to convert a string into an integer due to an error i receive when trying to pass a string and should have been passing an integer.

error

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '198.217.121.0'
```

example output

```
>>> for i in groups:
...   i['ip']
...   i['mask']
... 
'198.217.121.0'
'24'
'198.217.121.0'
'24'
'198.217.121.0'
'24'
'198.217.121.0'
<snippet>
```

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import print_function
from google.protobuf.any_pb2 import Any
import requests, json, ipaddress
##not standard python libraries will need to be installed
import grpc
import gobgp_pb2
import gobgp_pb2_grpc
import attribute_pb2

##query to get Top Talker data
url = "<private>"

querystring = {
  "hosts": [
    "<private>"
  ],
  "interval": "1m",
  "query": "SELECT sum(bps) as bits, dstprefix FROM raw_flows WHERE pop = 'slc01' AND ifrole_out REGEXP '^(PEER|ISP)' AND '2023-09-27T18:14:00.000Z' <= __time AND __time < '2023-09-28T18:13:00.000Z' GROUP BY dstprefix,TIME_BUCKET(__time, PT1M, 'Etc/UTC')  ORDER BY bits DESC LIMIT 100"
}

d = json.dumps(querystring)
response = requests.post(url, data=d).json()

##extracts dstprefix IP and subnet mask from the json response and makes each its own callable field 
groups = []
group = {'ip':',''mask'}
for dstprefix in response: 
    prefix = dstprefix["dstprefix"].strip()
    ip = prefix.split('/')[0]
    mask = prefix.split('/')[1]
    group.update({'ip':ip,'mask':mask})
    groups.append(group)

##grpc gobgp to install routes/add paths
def run(groups):
    channel = grpc.insecure_channel('localhost:50051')
    stub = gobgp_pb2_grpc.GobgpApiStub(channel)
    nlri = Any()
    for item in groups:
      ip = item['ip']
      mask = item['mask']
      int(ip)
      int(mask)
      nlri.Pack(attribute_pb2.IPAddressPrefix(
          prefix_len=(mask),
          prefix=(ip),
    ))
    origin = Any()
    origin.Pack(attribute_pb2.OriginAttribute(
        origin=2,  # INCOMPLETE
    ))
    as_segment = attribute_pb2.AsSegment(
        # type=2,  # "type" causes syntax error
        numbers=[600],
    )
    as_segment.type = 2  # SEQ
    as_path = Any()
    as_path.Pack(attribute_pb2.AsPathAttribute(
        segments=[as_segment],
    ))
    next_hop = Any()
    next_hop.Pack(attribute_pb2.NextHopAttribute(
        next_hop="1.1.1.1",
    ))
    attributes = [origin, as_path, next_hop]
    stub.AddPath(
        gobgp_pb2.AddPathRequest(
            table_type=gobgp_pb2.GLOBAL,
            path=gobgp_pb2.Path(
                nlri=nlri,
                pattrs=attributes,                
                family=gobgp_pb2.Family(afi=gobgp_pb2.Family.AFI_IP, safi=gobgp_pb2.Family.SAFI_UNICAST),
            )
        ),
        _TIMEOUT_SECONDS,
    )
```

after that i did some research and found the following [ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841565/valueerror-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10) which suggest converting to float before int

```
<snippet>
  int(float(ip))
      int(float(mask))
      nlri.Pack(attribute_pb2.IPAddressPrefix(
          prefix_len=(mask),
          prefix=(ip),
```

which gives the following error

```
  File "/home/ubuntu/eevee.py", line 43, in run
    int(float(ip))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '198.217.121.0'
```

Comment: Do you understand the issue? How do you expect Python to convert an IP to an `int`? What output do you want?

Comment: ah i think i figured out what i need to try. int is not expecting "." so i believe i will need to deconstruct IP to remove the "." and then convert into int and in the        prefix_len=(mask),
          prefix=(ip), will i need to do some sort of expression that can then add a "." between each integer to give me an IP

Comment: going to try str.replace to remove "." then converting to int. will add notes here shortly

Comment: @DeepSpace so i tried to remove the "." as those aren't recognizes values for integer and replaced them with a space so i could add "." again in the required IP field for configuration.   but i got another invalid literal and this time there are no invalid values - ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '198 217 121 0'

Comment: @DeepSpace and just for testing i removed all spaces and now i see:  File "/home/ubuntu/eevee.py", line 46, in run
    nlri.Pack(attribute_pb2.IPAddressPrefix(
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer.   i was expecting this specific section of code work but error out when actually trying to add the prefix as its not a valid prefix gobgp will recognize

Comment: I figured it out, i needed to convert 'mask' into an integer and 'ip' into a string when creating the 'IPAddressPrefix'.

Comment: def run(groups):
    channel = grpc.insecure_channel('localhost:50051')
    stub = gobgp_pb2_grpc.GobgpApiStub(channel)

    for item in groups:
        ip = item['ip']
        mask = int(item['mask'])  # Convert mask to an integer
        nlri = Any()
        nlri.Pack(attribute_pb2.IPAddressPrefix(
            prefix_len=mask,  # Use the integer value for prefix_len
            prefix=ip,         # Keep prefix as a string
        ))

Answer (score 0):

an ip address can not be an int. 198.217.121.0 has dots and therefore needs to be stored as a string. you can make it str() so it will immediately be shown as a string. floats can also only have 1 decimal point or it is invalid. do:

```
str(ip)
  str(mask)
  nlri.Pack(attribute_pb2.IPAddressPrefix(
      prefix_len=(mask),
      prefix=(ip),
```

hope this helps! if it will not work when you do this and it tries to use the strings as a int, i would recommend you check the documentation of the module you are using to know how it takes the values. but im pretty sure it using strings as that is the only reasonable way to take the values.